# Octave Specgram plot

Tags: octave

```
x = chirp([0:0.001:2],0,2,500);  # freq. sweep from 0-500 over 2 sec.
Fs=1000;                  # sampled every 0.001 sec so rate is 1 kHz
step=ceil(20*Fs/1000);    # one spectral slice every 20 ms
window=ceil(100*Fs/1000); # 100 ms data window
specgram(x, 2^nextpow2(window), Fs, window, window-step);'
```

I was trying to learn the specgram function, and I used the default code supplied by the help manual.

However, the automatic plot that is displayed by the function looks like this:

[image]

Can some explain why the output is this? I use 3.8.1 with signal 1.3.2

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the following image if I enter your code in Matlab:

[image]

Is that what you expect?